# How do I pin a program installed as an appimage to favorites?

Tags: software-installation, appimage

In my Ubuntu 20.04 I have downloaded an Appimage file and run it, and it runs without any problem.

However, I cannot find an icon for the program and I cannot pin it in my favorites bar. Also when I search for it I only find the Appimage file that I downloaded (when I double click on that, it works correctly and runs).

Is it possible to have this program behave like other applications that can be added to favorites, or do I just have to keep running it by clicking the Appimage file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Appimagelauncher as N0rbert proposes (see https://ostechnix.com/integrate-appimages-to-application-menu-using-appimagelauncher/). Or in KDE you can use KDE Menu Editor (KMenuEdit) with wich you can create a new desktop shortcut to open your Appimage, and of course you can maintain all your appimages in the same folder. I think the same tool is alacarte for Gnome. And finally you can create a .desktop file as again N0rbert proposes.

Comment: Many thanks, It  solved very simple, Thanks